# Search for array of strings in a list via getFilter method

Tags: android, search, arraylist, filter, adapter

I'm trying to implement searchview with `getFilter` method in my custom adapter.

I have a `getGenre()` method in my Model class which returns an array of strings separated with `,` like:  `piano,guitar,violin,.....` .

The problem is when I try to search for this terms for example: `piano,guitar`, Then it will return for example `piano,flute,guitar`, but it will ignore the items that have just one category: like the items that have just `guitar` tag as category will not be shown.

Can you help me with this, please?

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    Filter filter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            dataList = (List<ProductLocal>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            List<ProductLocal> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < dataListFilter.size(); i++) {
                ProductLocal dataNames = dataListFilter.get(i);

                int count = 0;
                String[] terms = constraint.toString().split(",");

                for (String term : terms) {

                    for (String str : dataNames.getGenre()) {

                        if (str.equals(term) || str.contains(term)) {
                            count++;
                            if (count == terms.length) {
                                filteredList.add(dataNames);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            results.count = filteredList.size();
            results.values = filteredList;
            return results;
        }

    };
    return filter;
}
```

Comment: @Selvin I think you are so blind with your arrogant that you didn't see I already mentioned my problem in my question. and SO is almost full of basic questions. that people improved their programming knowledge by sharing their experience.

Comment: *In another word, if I try to search for guitar, this item will not be shown as filtered list.* ??? [it is not true](http://ideone.com/EYL1Q8)